# Wake-ups of cpu in android device

Tags: android

Can anyone let me know, Is there any way to find-out the Android Device CPU wake-ups. Let me explain more what exactly am looking for i.e. within some specific time how many times my android device CPU is in Idle state and Awake state. Struggled a lot but not able to find any solution. Any approach is fine for me to proceed forward, like execute top/proc command to find out the cpu state or any framework APIs which is exposed to application developers.

Somebody kindly help me to proceed forward with this issue.

Comment: You might find some information in this thread http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2179651

Comment: @MadhurAhuja Indeed, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector  Is a great tool to discover wake-locks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but this "Wakelock Detector" app is not working in Kitkat.  Google made some changes of accessing to "BatteryStats" because of which app is not compatible with Kitkat version device.